# How to recompile with -Xlint in java netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, cmd, recompile, netbeans-8.1

How do i recompile my java program with -Xlint as indicated by the java compiler. I am using netbeans 8.1 beta version.

Note: E:\NetBeansProjects\Project21\MyCode\src\mycode\MyCode.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
I am using netbeans gui to run the program file.

What should i do to remove this warning?

Comment: The link to the "already answered" answer is for a very outdated version of NetBeans and does not refer to Apache NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

You can add that compiler option like this:

1. Open your project `Properties` page.
2. Go to `Build --> Compiling`
3. At the bottom of the window, look for `Additional Compiler Options`
4. Type `-Xlint:unchecked` in the textbox.

Comment: Thanks! it worked, but how do i store the output terminal content in windows 7 command prompt, i tried with javac MyCode.java >> storeoutput.txt, but its not working.